# jxls-reader: Example from reference doesn't work

Tags: java, xls, xlsx

I need to read XLS files from Java. For that purpose I start evaluating [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) framework. Unfortunately, I'm still getting following exception while trying to run example on their [XLS reader reference](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html) page:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jxls.reader.XLSDataReadException: Can't read cell A4 on Sheet1 spreadsheet
    at net.sf.jxls.reader.SimpleBlockReaderImpl.read(SimpleBlockReaderImpl.java:61)
    at net.sf.jxls.reader.XLSSheetReaderImpl.read(XLSSheetReaderImpl.java:25)
    at net.sf.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl.readSheet(XLSReaderImpl.java:45)
    at net.sf.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl.read(XLSReaderImpl.java:31)
    at com.oracle.sk.jxls.App.go(App.java:46)
    at com.oracle.sk.jxls.App.main(App.java:19)
```

Changes I've made against original are:

- moved Department.java and Employee.java into the same package where main class is (in other words next to App.java)
- add empty no-args constructor to both
- change the varType (full class names for Employee and Department) everywhere in departments.xml accordingly

Both departments.xml and departmentdata.xls are taken directly from the [XLS reader reference page](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html). [Department.java](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/departmentbean.html) and [Employee.java](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/employeebean.html) are downloaded from [Simple beans](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/simplebeans.html) page (on jXLS site too). If necessary, I can provide my complete Maven project.

Please, does anyone have a clue, why it is not working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does it work without any changes? Sounds like a problem with the worksheet.

Comment: What's in cell A4, what's it's type etc?

Comment: @dogbane: Well, I had to create that example by following what's on the jXLS site - there is nothing like ready-to-run project. So I can't tell what it will look like "without any changes", sorry.

Comment: @Mikaveli: It's just text ("Maxim" - the name of chief in that departments-employees example). If interested, you can download the whole XLS file from [here](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/xls/departmentdata.xls).

Comment: @roxolid: I just found a solution. Check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been a while, but I did some debugging searching to answer this problem, an actually I found out something.

From the `departments.xml` you see that the A4 cell is mapped to `department.chief.name`, but when it initializes your Department object, the chief property is null, so in the Department no-args constructor you should do something like `chief = new Employee()`

Now it should work.